# Proving Big Θ of summations with exponentials

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

I have been working on this problem but have had a hard time understanding how to prove it as True, which I believe it is.

```
[ Summation of k=1 to n of sqrt(2^k) ]= Θ(sqrt(2)^n);
```

I know you can change sqrt(2^k) to 2^(k/2), and sqrt(2)^n to 2^(n/2)
Which, with the summation, becomes

```
2^(1/2)+2^1+2^(3/2)+2^2+... 2^(n/2) = Θ 2^n/2
```

So, by definition of Big Θ,

```
C1 2^(n/2) ≤ x ≤ C2 2^(n/2)
```

where I'm going to say

```
x = 2^(1/2)+2^1+2^(3/2)+2^2+... 2^(n/2)
```

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt2$ then $a\gt1$ hence $x_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na^k$ is such that
$$
a^n\leqslant x_n\leqslant a^n\sum_{i=0}^\infty a^{-i}=\frac{a}{a-1}a^n.
$$
This shows that
$$
x_n=\Theta(a^n).
$$